# Cannot implicitly convert type but already it's Converted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Cannot implicitly convert type problem.but in here it's converted & assign.Can anyone tell me whats wrong here ? here i have post whole code for it.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(int? id)
    {
        Models.ProductsModels.Products product = new Models.ProductsModels.Products();

        ViewBag.ListOfCategories = new SelectList(_cat.GetCategory(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.ListOfBrands = new SelectList(_brad.GetAllBrands(), "BrandId", "BrandName");

        int productId = id ?? 0;

        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            ICS.Data.Product _prod = new ICS.Data.Product();
            product = (new ProductController()).GetProductById(productId);
            product.ProductId = _prod.ProductId;
            product.ProductName = _prod.ProductName;
            product.CategoryId = _prod.Category_CategoryId;
            product.BrandId = _prod.Brand_BrandId;
            product.PriceSettings = _prod.IsFixed;
            product.PurchasePrice = (float)_prod.PurchasePrice;
            product.ItemPrice = (float)_prod.ItemPrice;
            product.Vat = (double)_prod.Vat;
            product.WholeSalePrice = (float)_prod.WholeSalePrice;
            product.RetailPrice = (float)_prod.RetailPrice;
            product.Comments = _prod.Comments;         
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

finally it's retun to the Product View.

Comment: Try: product = new ProductController().GetProductById(productId) ??

Comment: You did not specify a data type to your `product` variable?

Comment: Yes ``product =``  seems like it should read ``_prod =`` ..it or it's not declared ?? too much guessing here

Comment: @Robert Whole code posted

Comment: What is the return type of GetProductById() action?

Comment: post the error message too plz

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ICS.Data.Product' to 'ICS.Models.ProductsModels.Products'

Comment: the accepted answer is fine, but i feel uneasy about seeing this code create a model, and assigning values like that. Consider creating a viewmodel. Your actionresult could be 3 lines of code. ``return View(new ProductController().GetProductById(id));``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your code:

```
_prod = (new ProductController()).GetProductById(productId);
```

Full code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddProduct(int? id)
    {
        Models.ProductsModels.Products product = new Models.ProductsModels.Products();

        ViewBag.ListOfCategories = new SelectList(_cat.GetCategory(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.ListOfBrands = new SelectList(_brad.GetAllBrands(), "BrandId", "BrandName");

        int productId = id ?? 0;

        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            ICS.Data.Product _prod = (new ProductController()).GetProductById(productId);
            product.ProductId = _prod.ProductId;
            product.ProductName = _prod.ProductName;
            product.CategoryId = _prod.Category_CategoryId;
            product.BrandId = _prod.Brand_BrandId;
            product.PriceSettings = _prod.IsFixed;
            product.PurchasePrice = (float)_prod.PurchasePrice;
            product.ItemPrice = (float)_prod.ItemPrice;
            product.Vat = (double)_prod.Vat;
            product.WholeSalePrice = (float)_prod.WholeSalePrice;
            product.RetailPrice = (float)_prod.RetailPrice;
            product.Comments = _prod.Comments;         
        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: If that's the answer, remove the double new() ``ICS.Data.Product _prod = new ProductController().GetProductById(productId);``